# SQL Update table1.column1 if table1.column2 like table2.column2

Tags: sql-update, sql-like

I have two tables.  Products `P1` and Manufacturers `M1`.  I want to see if the `manufacturer_name` is in the `P1.title` and update the `P1.manufacturer_id` with the `M1.manufacturer_id`.

```
UPDATE products P1
set P1.manufacturer_id=manufacturers.manufacturer_id 
WHERE P1.title LIKE manufacturers.manufacturer_name;
```

I am getting Error `"#1054 - Unknown column 'manufacturers.manufacturer_name' in 'where clause' "`

Also, what is the correct syntax for `WHERE P1.title LIKE %M1.manufacturer_name%`?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe I need a FOR EACH to iterate through the products?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post much about table structure, or the relationship between manufacturer and products, so the below is my best guess: please review and test it thoroughly. I'd prefer to write this using a JOIN, but without knowing what the foreign keys are, I'm not willing to take the chance on duplication ...

```
UPDATE P1
SET P1.Manufacturer_ID = 
  (
    SELECT TOP 1 Manufacturer_ID 
    FROM Manufacturers 
    WHERE P1.Title LIKE '%' + manufacturer_name + '%'
  )
FROM Products P1
```